# Finding expression that runs through zeros of a function

Tags: functions

A list plot of the zeros of the imaginary part of $2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi s}{2}\bigg)\Gamma(1-s)$ for $s=\frac{1}{2}+it$

looks like this:

[image]

How would I find the expression for the line that runs through these points?

Comment: $t\in\mathbb R^+$?

Comment: @ Jack M, yes - should have said

Comment: The curve might be log type, rather linear. Try larger roots - say $10^k$ for $k=3, 4, 5$.